# Массив экземпляров класса

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть класс:

```
class A {
private:
 struct B
 {
    std::string W;
 };
 B D[100];
public:
 A(){};    
};
```

Мне нужен массив из экземпляров A класса. Подскажите как это сделать ?

Comment: `A a[N];` - массив из `N` элементов типа `A`.

Answer (score 3):

Например,

```
A a[20];
```

Или это не то, что надо?

Если их надо создавать во время выполнения программы, например - то

```
A* a = new A[20];
```

Такой же массив из 20 элементов класса. не забудьте по окончании работы с ними удалить с помощью `delete[]a`.

Если только один -

```
A* a = new A;
```

Удалять надо тем же `delete`, но уже без скобок: `delete a;`.

И - подумайте о применении вектора `vector<A>`, который все необходимые манипуляции будет делать за вас.

Comment: Уже в запущенной программе по запросу пользователя на создание еще одного объекта.

Comment: @Luntic измените вопрос, согласно Вашей задаче. Для создания массива в рантайне существует `new A[N]`. Об этом написано в любом учебнике по языку.